# Unzip .zip file in Objective-C without 3rd party

Tags: ios, objective-c, unzip

How to unzip .zip file in Objective-C + iOS without third party tool/software like SSZipArchive or ZipArchive.

Comment: Why would you say "without third party tool/software"? It makes no sense, are you going to fully reimplement ZIP and zlib by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use third party you have to implement mechanisms that frameworks make for you. So you have to repeat their already done job. If so you may as well use those frameworks.

If you are interested how this works you can just check their code.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do it with first party software (from Apple).  I haven't tried it myself, but how about this: https://opensource.apple.com/source/gnuzip/gnuzip-28/gzip/unzip.c

Answer (score 0):

Zip archives are nontrivial archives. Theres more to a zip archive than just the *deflate* compression. Apple supplies `libz` as a framework you can link to. But libz isn't enough to recreate a zip file's directory structure, for instance.

If you seriously want to avoid external dependencies, i'd suggest trying to convert to something that iOS can handle out of the gate: try gzip! heres a tutorial: http://www.clintharris.net/2009/how-to-gzip-data-in-memory-using-objective-c/

Otherwise, honestly, there are well supported 3rd party zip libraries that should work just fine.